# Passing parameters to SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two Drop Down Lists, degrees and programs respectively, i want to generate the program list values on the bases of selected Degree from degree dropdown list. how can i do this, the code is given below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Degree_DList" runat="server" DataSourceID="Degrees_DropdownList" 
DataTextField="DEGREE_NAME" DataValueField="DEGREE_ID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Degrees_DropdownList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:admConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:admConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT DEGREE_ID, DEGREE_NAME FROM DEGREE"> </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="Program_Dlist" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="Programs_DropdownList" DataTextField="PROGRAM_NAME" DataValueField="PROGRAM_ID"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Programs_DropdownList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:admConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:admConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT PROGRAM_ID, PROGRAM_NAME FROM PROGRAMS WHERE DEGREE_ID = @DEGREE_ID"><SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="DEGREE_ID" ControlID="Degree_DList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to *inform* your `DataSource` you'll provide some parameters in the `SELECT`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ... >
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="DEGREE_ID" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Do not forget to provide that parameters with code:

```
MyDataSource.SelectParameters["DEGREE_ID"].DefaultValue = "12345";
```

Comment: Which one? The one used for the first dropdownlist should be left untouched. For the second one you should provide that inputs somewhere (I guess reacting to selectedindexchanged).

Comment: i want 2nd dropdown list completely dynamic, which generates list of values on the basis of selected item in first dropdown list

Comment: Yes, your original code is gone but you had a **SqlDataSource** with some parameters in the SELECT, simply add **SelectParameters** tag to your **SqlDataSource** tag (and provide them from code). If default value isn't meaningful you can set it, for example, in the **Selecting** event of the **DataSource**. Take a look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx

Comment: <SelectParameters> <asp:Parameter Name="DGRE_ID" />                              </SelectParameters>